# how to detect ion-menu close event on different page in ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to perform some functionality when ion-menu is closed, on different pages.
ion-menu event work for that menu page only not on other page

Comment: Until yet I find only to work with is to use subject behaviour only

Answer (score 2):

Since ion-menu typically resides within app.component and you want state from it to be available to other components you need to leverage a "shared service".

Create a shared service (ng g s shared):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {

 private menuClosed = new BehaviorSubject(true); // set whatever default value;

 updateMenuState(state: boolean) {
   this.menuClosed.next(state)
 };

}
```

Now import into the app.component and add method that you will link ionWillClose and ionWillOpen to:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
//..other imports
import { SharedService } from './services/shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {

  //...

  constructor(
    public sharedService: SharedService
  ) {

  };

  updateMenuState(state: boolean) {
    this.sharedService.updateMenuState(state)
  }

  //...

}
```

And in your app.component.html:

```
<ion-menu (ionWillClose)="updateMenuState(false)" (ionWillOpen)="updateMenuState(true)"></ion-menu>
```

After that import shared service in whatever other components you have and subscribe to the BehaviorSubject for changes.

Comment: Already using subjectBehaviour to deal with,But i want to know is there any way given by ionic, then it might be useful

Comment: There is no Ionic's own way of providing this functionality. Ionic 3 did feature "Events" https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/util/Events/ which could potentially provide functionality enabling your use case via pub/sub pattern. But it was deprecated in favor of Observables/Subjects. Also Ionic's positioning is not to provide custom solutions for such cases and it typically relies on actual framework used (Angular for ex). So I think BehaviorSubject is in line with what Ionic recommends. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Write a function with your desired code and put it in `app.component.ts` or a service that is shared everywhere. then in your `ion-menu` tag use the event **ionWillClose** to execute your function.

like this:

```
<ion-menu (ionWillClose)="muFunction()"></ion-menu>
```

**ionWillClose** event will be emitted when the menu *is about to be closed*.

Comment: <ion- menu> tag is define in menu page not in my component page

Comment: @Reaper It doesn't matter. do what I said wherever ion-menu tag exists.

Comment: but in my component <ion-menu-button> tag is there not <ion-menu> tag